# Working with multiple angularjs/typescript/ionic versions on Linux

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, ionic3

I have different front end projects which require different AngularJs/TypeScript/Ionic version combinations, say Angular 2.x/Ionic 2.x and Angular 4.x/Ionic 3.x. However when I run `npm install -g cordova ionic` it always install the latest version. Is there a way to allow me install multiple version combinations concurrently and easily switch between them?

I am on LinuxMint 18 system

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

> npm install cordova ionic

only.

-g means general.

Comment: So you mean in each project dir run `npm install cordova@x ionic@x`? The question is if I run that, it will install the ionic in the project's `node_modules` folder, however if I invoke `ionic` in the command line, it still load the general installed ionic cli version, how to get this resolved?

Comment: change your PATH to include BASEDIR/node_modules/.bin as the first element